# Dropdown login menu not showing fields

Tags: python, django, templates, menu

In the base template of my project I've got a piece of code in the header about login in if you aren't already authenticated. That's made with a dropdown menu that works properly.

The problem happens when trying to make it functional, I've got both the form and the view, but while trying to put the fields in the template they aren't showing up. Maybe it's a problem of import, I'm not sure how to fix it. Here's the code:

**template (base.html):**

```
<div id="auth">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Bienvenido, <b>{{ user.username }}  |  <a href=" {% url "logout" %}">Logout</a></b></p>
    {% else %}
<div id="navthing">
      <h2><a href="#" id="loginform">Log in</a> | <a href="#">Sign Up</a></h2>
   <div class="login">
    <div class="arrow-up"></div>
     <div class="formholder">
       <div class="randompad">
            <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
            {% if message %}
    <b>{{message}}</b>
    {% endif %}
        {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
           </form>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**views.py:**

```
def login_page(request):
    message = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    message = "Now you are succesfully logged in"
                else:
                    message = "Your username is inactive"
            else:
                message = "Your username and/or password is incorrect"
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render_to_response('base.html', {'message': message, 'form': form},
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

Where's the problem here? Thank you.

Comment: Don't [delete your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36594739/1324033) just to make a new one, update the existing one with any new information.

Comment: Changed some of the html code, isn't right to be it here?